# Which font is used by [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]?

Tags: iphone, uifont

I'd like to use a UIWebView with the same typographical appearance as the rest of my app texts which all use `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]`. But before doing some forensic research maybe someone knows what font that really is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to inspect the `fontName` property of the UIFont returned by `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]`.

```
NSString *fontName = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15].fontName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly **HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular** (iOS7+)